# Extract element

Tags: php

I use DiscordPHP, it gives me the list of members.
I want to get only the id of members in variable (I already search in documentation)

https://pastebin.com/PN4nMmEx

I tried:

```
$iduser= array_column($discordphp, 'id');
```

Comment: thanks, i try but don't work :(

Answer (score 1):

I found !

```
foreach ( $memberslist as $M ){
   //var_dump($M); // au cas où, si ça ne marche pas le code en dessous
    $id = $M->user->id;
    $username = $M->user->username;
    echo " / ".$username." - ". $id;
    $message->channel->sendMessage("".$id." -> ".$username."");
}
```